# list printing out multiple elements instead of just 2

Tags: python, list

having a small issue where, using the code below, when printing out strings in a list, having more than 2 will cause there to be double the strings I printed.

```
    print("Geneaology for: \n\t" + user_name + "\t\t" + user_birthday)
    print("Parents: ")
    # Prints out parents names and date of birth
    for x in parent_names:
        for y in parent_birthdays:
            print(str("\t" + x + "\t\t" + y))
    # Prints out siblngs names and date of birth
    print("Siblings: ")
    for x in sibling_names:
        for y in sibling_birthdays:
            print(str("\t" + x + "\t\t" + y))
    # Prints out grandparents names and date of birth
    print("Grandparents: ")
    for x in grandparent_names:
        for y in grandparent_birthdays:
            print(str("\t" + x + "\t\t" + y))
```

With the "parent_name" and "parent_birthday" lists having only 1 string, I get this:

```
Geneaology for: 
        jm              01/01/01
Parents:
        aa              01/01/01
```

With 2 strings in each, i get this:

```
Geneaology for: 
        jm              01/01/01
Parents:
        aa              01/01/01
        aa              02/02/02
        bb              01/01/01
        bb              02/02/02
```

I haven't tried all to much, other than changing the positioning of certain things and variables, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `parent_names` and `parent_birthdays` are parallel lists.  You should be storing this in a single list, where each entry is a dictionary with the data for that one person.  You CAN do what you want like this, but you really need to reorganize your data.

```
    for x,y in zip(parent_names, parent_birthdays):
        print("\t" + x + "\t\t" + y)
```

And it's silly to call the `str()` function on something that's already a string.

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider to make Parents a dictionary?

```
parent = {
  "name": "aa",
  "birthday": "01/01/1995"
}
```

Then:

```
# Where "parents" is a list of parent dictionaries
for parent in parents:
  print("\t" + parent['name'] + "\t\t" + parent['birthday'])
```